# What's the value of this question?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What's the value of [image]

Can anyone share some light of this question ?

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

(without proving convergence, which you need to be rigorous)

If you represent the entire expression as $1 + x$, you can see that the equation:

$\displaystyle \frac{1+x}{2+x} = x$ is satisfied.

Solve that equation and find $1+x$ to find the value of the expression.

Comment: I still couldn't get it. Can you show me ? Thanks in advance

Comment: First cover the "$1+..$" part. The remainder is a ratio in the form $\frac{1+x}{2+x}$. But you can see by recognising the infinite pattern that the entire ratio is also $x$. After that, you get a quadratic equation which you should be able to easily solve. Don't forget to add back the "$1+...$" at the end.

Answer (score 3):

$$\require{enclose} 1+\enclose{circle}{\quad\dfrac{1+\enclose{circle}{\quad\dfrac{1+\enclose{circle}{\quad\dfrac{1+\cdots}{2+\cdots}\quad}}{2+\enclose{circle}{\quad\dfrac{1+\cdots}{2+\cdots}\quad}}\quad}}{2+\enclose{circle}{\quad\dfrac{1+\enclose{circle}{\quad\dfrac{1+\cdots}{2+\cdots}\quad}}{2+\enclose{circle}{\quad\dfrac{1+\cdots}{2+\cdots}\quad}}\quad}}\quad}$$

*Hint:* 
The things enclosed in each ring are the same.   Call them $x$

So, what's the value of $1+x$ when $1+x= 1+\dfrac{1+x}{2+x}$ ?

Comment: To prove convergence,apply the Axiom of Multiple Choice: At least one of the proferred answers on a multiple -choice test q is correct. Corollary : since "None of these" is not proferred, somebody  else already proved convergence .QED.  LOL

Comment: @user254665 Haha! :)